# RabbitMQ - DefaultConsumer inner channel

Tags: java, rabbitmq, consumer

Given the following code :

```
   public void doSomething(Channel channel1){
        DefaultConsumer consumer1 = new DefaultConsumer(channel1).
        channel1.basicConsume("Queue1Name",..., "Consumer1Tag", consumer1)
}
```

If channl1 get's disconnected for some reason, which will cause messages to not be consumed(?) :

1. Can the same consumer instanse`(consumer1)` be used with a different channel in some way or is a new instance and a new channel required?
2. Will a redecleration of Queue1Name be aware of any changes? i.e -
   `DeclareOk queueResponse = someOtherChannel.queueDeclare("Queue1Name", ........);
   int consumerCount = queueResponse.getConsumerCount()`

What will be the consumer count?

The reason for this question is that i have a background thread running and checking connection to RabbitMQ once in a while. I check that channels and connections are open, and in case they are not - i reset them. I want to keep a single consumer on Queue1 and still be able to handle a scenario when i find it's channel is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If channel1 gets disconnected it's messages won't be consumed, that is correct. They will remain in the Queue.

1. Yes you can reconnect to the same Queue, the messages left behind will have to be handled before you can receive the new messages though.
2. I think you need to remove the Queue before you can make a new one with the same name (I'm not 100% sure). Consumer count should be 1 after you reconnect. But if you do that, any messages left in the Queue will be lost.

You should really try this out yourself in your application and observe behaviour.